# Unable to find the GRASS module i.ortho.rectify on QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, orthorectification

I am using QGIS 3.4.2-Madeira. It has GRASS 7 as a core plugin.

In QGIS, when I open `Processing Toolbox`, I can see the GRASS option but under the `imagery` sub-menu, I cannot find the `i.ortho.rectify` module.

[image: My Processing Toolbox]

[image: Missing <code>i.ortho.rectify</code>]

I am also unable to add a new mapset since my GRASS toolbar doesn't show all the options as told [in this QGIS tutorial.](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/grass/grass_setup.html#basic-fa-start-a-new-grass-project) It only shows `Open GRASS Tools` option which upon clicking opens the GRASS Tools as seen in the lower half of both of the attached images.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install everything cleanly using OSGEO4W?

This module is also on my QGIS but the executable is present in the GRASS folder of QGIS.

> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\grass76\bin

You could try using the command line executable. The syntax is as follows: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/i.ortho.rectify.html

Comment: I am on Ubuntu. You're somewhat right. I searched for `i.ortho.rectify`on my system and I got it in `/usr/lib/grass74/bin/path/`. However, the path of the GRASS plugin which my QGIS is using is different from this - `/usr/lib/qgis/plugins/`. So from what I understand, the required module is on my system but QGIS is fetching plugins from somewhere else. How do I solve this?

Comment: My GRASS folder of QGIS has no such executable. The executable that I'm talking about is completely outside of the QGIS directory. Its in my `/usr/lib`.

Comment: There's something entirely wrong with my GRASS installation I think. I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/JtPOyYQ)

Comment: For plugin GRASS, there are two different folders : one for the installation of GRASS and another for the modules. Have you try to reinstall with OSGeo4W ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried to re-install. Maybe that's the only option now. Please check the image in my comment just above yours to see if it provides some additional info. Otherwise I will restart with a fresh install.

Comment: There are many error messages, the best is to reinstall

Comment: @Nancy , You have GRASS working fine in text based interface. You cannot run directly the command from the console because you are not defining the mapset first. That is GRASS GIS. In QGIS you have another two GRASS: the GRASS plugin, and processing algorithms implementations for QGIS. All of them are different things, installed in different folders. `i.ortho.rectify` GRASS command is not implemented in QGIS processing GRASS provider algorithms. You can run it from the plugin or from the console. But you need to define the mapset and the region. See the GRASS GIS docs if you need it.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Now I get it. I thought I might be **at least** able to run the `--help` command for `i.ortho.rectify` from the text based interface. I will look into the GRASS GIS docs now for instructions on how to define a mapset through text based interface. I hope that's possible.

Comment: That is possible. GRASS GIS projects are not exactly like QGIS projects. You will need to understand how GRASS work. But if you really need GRASS tools, that is the better way to do it. Then, you will find that the GRASS Tools plugin is like a GRASS GIS GUI inside QGIS.